# Original on odd, translation on even pages

Tags: paragraphs, double-sided, parallel-texts

I have a text and its translation. I want to print the original text on odd pages and the translation on even pages. Paragraphs of the two versions should be aligned to each other. Do you know an easy way to achieve this with LaTeX?

Comment: See the paracol package.

Comment: Or e.g. `reledmac` etc.

Comment: The objective you state in the title are the exact opposite of the title you state in the body of the posting. Please clarify which of the two layout objectives is the real one.

Comment: Sorry. The mistake just happened because it does not really matter. When I am able to place the original text on odd pages and the translations on even pages, I guess I will manage to do it vice versa.

Comment: actually [`reledpar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledpar?lang=en), which is `reledmac`'s extension for parallel text -- either on parallel pages or in parallel columns. It works fine, but it might be a bit of an overkill, if you don't need any of `reledmac`'s main functions, i.e. critical apparatus

Comment: @JohnKormylo [`paracol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) can do that? Perhaps you can answer my "[Make paracol left column on even and right column on odd pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630811/36603)" question.

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer, provide an MWE.