# Make paracol left column on even and right column on odd pages?

Tags: paracol, parallel-texts

Is there a way to make [`paracol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol)'s left column be on even pages and right column on odd pages?

Related question: "[Original on odd, translation on even pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263653/36603)?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called parallel-page typesetting, and it's discussed on [`paracol` manual](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf) (1.35 2018-12-31) page 12 (and §9, pp. 34ff.):

> `\begin{paracol}[numleft]{num}[text] body \end{paracol}`
> `\begin{paracol}[numleft]*{num}[text] body \end{paracol}`
>
> If a `\begin{paracol}` has the optional *numleft* argument to specify the number of leading columns *n<sub>l</sub>*
> together with the total *n* given by *num*, columns in the environment are laid out across two adjacent
> pages. In this *parallel-page typesetting*, the first *n<sub>l</sub>* columns are placed in the *left* page while remaining
> *n<sub>r</sub>* = *n* − *n<sub>l</sub>* columns go to the next *right* page. The pair of left and right pages is considered as comprising
> a virtual *paired* page and thus shares a common page number, unless *non-paired* typesetting is specified
> by the optional ‘*’ following the optional *numleft* argument. In the non-paired parallel-paging, when the
> leading *n<sub>l</sub>* columns are put in a page *p*, the trailing n<sub>r</sub> columns are in the page *p* + 1.

Comment: In particular, numleft=1 and num=2 will put one column on each page.  Starting on an even page involves skipping an odd page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I see `paracol` has a `\flushpage` command to put in the `paracol` environment so that it starts on an even page.

Comment: I believe \flushpage is used inside paracol and will flush all the columns, which in your case means both pages.  All you need is to use \newpage if you are on an odd page (see ifoddpage package) before starting the paracol environment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `\newpage` has no effect for me. It still starts on an odd page.

Comment: Try `\null\newpage`.  You need something on the page first.  (Sorry about that.)

Comment: Thank you Geremia. I have been trying to learn how to do parallel text (multiple columns across facing pages) and paracol was on of the first things I looked out, but did not read that far in the documentation.