# Parallel-Paging with paracol totally fail with polyglossia

Tags: languages, incompatibility, arabic, paracol

I have an french-arabic belangual document, where the french version should be appear at left odd pages when arabic version sould appear at right even pages like as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630811/make-paracol-left-column-on-even-and-right-column-on-odd-pages).

But, I discover the command `\setotherlanguages{arabic}` makes parallel-Paging of paracol not work at all. It is not necessary to use arabic inside the `paracol` environement to make it fail as you can see bellow in my MWE. Just declaring arabic as second language somewhere in the document makes all the `paracol` with `numleft` option fail.

##### MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{paracol}

\setotherlanguages{arabic} % ← Comment this line and the Parallel paging works again

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}[1]{2}

  \switchcolumn[0]*
  Lorem ipusm
  \switchcolumn[1]
  Dolor

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

#### The question

So how can I use paracol’s Parallel-Paging with arabic inside a same document?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `paracol` call after the arabic declaration like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}


\setotherlanguages{arabic} % ← Comment this line and the Parallel paging works again
\usepackage{paracol} % ← Paracol should be here

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}[1]{2}

  \switchcolumn[0]*
  Lorem ipusm
  \switchcolumn[1]
  Dolor

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```